# Why web-scraping with BeautifulSoup returns empty result?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am fairly new to web scraping and HTML. I am trying to scrape all the text content from a website. However, the text is returning empty.

I am doing the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import unicodedata

def strip_accents(text):
    try:
        text = unicode(text, 'utf-8')
    except NameError: # unicode is a default on python 3 
        pass

    text = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', text)\
           .encode('ascii', 'ignore')\
           .decode("utf-8")

    return str(text)

current_url = "https://www.diabete.qc.ca/en/understand-diabetes/all-about-diabetes/complications/female-sexuality-and-diabetes/"

try:
    response = requests.get(current_url, allow_redirects = False, verify = False,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} )

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:  
        print("Error",e)

else:
                
    soup = BeautifulSoup(strip_accents(response.content.decode('utf-8')),"html.parser")
    text = soup.get_text(" ", strip=True)
    print(text)
```

However, text is returning empty. I was able to get all the text I wanted on another similar website with this code so I am not sure what the problem is exactly.

Comment: When I request that url with a plain curl command, I also get an empty response.  I'm guessing that the website thinks you're a robot (which you are!) and is choosing not to respond.

Comment: Hmm ok so I guess it's not a problem with the code but with the site per see. That is interesting! I wonder if there's anything to modify in the headers that will change this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow redirects:

```
requests.get(current_url, allow_redirects = True, verify = False,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} )
```

or because the default value is `True`:

```
requests.get(current_url, verify = False,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} )
```

Comment: Is there any way to get around this? I don't want to get content from any redirects

Comment: Not per se - It is a specifica of the website / server. If you do not want to follow its process you have to skip the website, find an alternative source or whitelist these websites where you like to follow redirects.